# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 error after accidentally delete target

Tags: ios, xcode

I accidentally delete target. I created again but i couldn't run my application again. When i set my AppDelegate i get an error.

```
Ld /Users/cihanozdiker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Moka-foueugicfassxcdbtgwkndrougpu/Build/Intermediates/Moka.build/Debug-iphoneos/Moka.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Moka normal arm64
cd /Users/cihanozdiker/Documents/MokaAfterMerchantFinished
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/cihanozdiker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Moka-foueugicfassxcdbtgwkndrougpu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L../include -L../include/barcode -L../include/common -L../include/cyclone_crypto -L../include/EstimoteSDK -L../include/openssl -L../include/EstimoteSDK/Headers -L/Users/cihanozdiker/Documents/MokaAfterMerchantFinished -L../lib -L../lib/AESCrypt-ObjC-master -L../lib/RNCryptor -F/Users/cihanozdiker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Moka-foueugicfassxcdbtgwkndrougpu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/cihanozdiker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Moka-foueugicfassxcdbtgwkndrougpu/Build/Intermediates/Moka.build/Debug-iphoneos/Moka.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Moka.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.1 -ObjC -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lcrypto -lssl -lC4NetSdk -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/cihanozdiker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Moka-foueugicfassxcdbtgwkndrougpu/Build/Intermediates/Moka.build/Debug-iphoneos/Moka.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Moka_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/cihanozdiker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Moka-foueugicfassxcdbtgwkndrougpu/Build/Intermediates/Moka.build/Debug-iphoneos/Moka.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Moka

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MokaAppDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I couldn't fix it. I'm using XCode 7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `MokaAppDelegate` implementation file (probably MokaAppDelegate.m) is marked as part of your new target.

Select the file in the Project Navigator, look at the File Inspector panel and make sure the right target(s) are selected in the Target Membership pane.

Comment: thank you. you saved my day! nothing was marked as part of your my new target.